# How is the Visa and MasterCard acceptance in Macedonia?

Tags: payment-cards, macedonia

I am from Denmark and I am travelling to Macedonia this week. My bank cannot tell me (!) if my Visa and MasterCard can be used in Macedonia. Has anyone experienced any issues using either Visa or MasterCard in Macedonia?

Comment: I have travelled through there with both types of cards (before Chase changed from MasterCard to Visa) and never gave it a second thought.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have managed to talk to some people who travelled to Macedonia, including one from Denmark with MasterCard. Apparently, there should not be any issues using either Visa or MasterCard.

In any case, it would still be advisable to have some euros with you just in case.

Answer (score 7):

I accidentally came across this post after a google search for visa services. I am from Macedonia and I can confirm that VISA/MasterCard are accepted everywhere where they have a POS terminal. Almost all of the places have one so everyone using a card will be fine. Having around 50 euros in cash is advisable, just in case you need cash for something.
For instance, taxi can only be paid in cash (around 3 euros per 5km) or stuff on open flea markets.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Thanks for adding your personal expertise!